# Cronjob is not working even though cron process is running

Tags: bash, cron, debian

I have configured a very simple cron job but it is not working.

$ crontab -e

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/env > /home/myid/env
* * * * * /bin/echo 'hi' > /home/myid/HI
```

The above jobs are not working at all. The path of /usr/bin/env and /bin/echo are correct.

I can see cron is running as a process and it seems root can do cron jobs.

$ ps aux | grep cron

```
root      2771  0.0  0.1   2316   860 ?        Ss   07:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
myid     12232  0.0  0.1   2040   632 pts/1    S+   08:17   0:00 grep cron
```

$ tail -24 /var/log/syslog

```
Oct 25 08:01:08 localhost crontab[5224]: (myid) BEGIN EDIT (myid)
Oct 25 08:01:44 localhost init: Id "1" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
Oct 25 08:03:37 localhost crontab[5224]: (myid) END EDIT (myid)
Oct 25 08:05:01 localhost /USR/SBIN/CRON[7008]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Oct 25 08:07:31 localhost sendmail[9090]: My unqualified host name (localhost) unknown; sleeping for retry
Oct 25 08:07:35 localhost init: Id "1" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
Oct 25 08:08:01 localhost /usr/sbin/cron[2771]: (*system*sendmail) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/sendmail)
Oct 25 08:08:31 localhost sendmail[9090]: unable to qualify my own domain name (localhost) -- using short name
Oct 25 08:08:31 localhost sendmail[9090]: alias database /etc/mail/aliases rebuilt by root
Oct 25 08:08:31 localhost sendmail[9090]: /etc/mail/aliases: 12 aliases, longest 10 bytes, 134 bytes total
Oct 25 08:08:32 localhost sm-mta[9484]: My unqualified host name (localhost) unknown; sleeping for retry
Oct 25 08:08:34 localhost sm-msp-queue[9501]: My unqualified host name (localhost) unknown; sleeping for retry
Oct 25 08:09:32 localhost sm-mta[9484]: unable to qualify my own domain name (localhost) -- using short name
Oct 25 08:09:32 localhost sm-mta[9732]: starting daemon (8.14.4): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
Oct 25 08:09:34 localhost sm-msp-queue[9501]: unable to qualify my own domain name (localhost) -- using short name
Oct 25 08:13:26 localhost init: Id "1" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
Oct 25 08:14:30 localhost crontab[11351]: (myid) BEGIN EDIT (myid)
Oct 25 08:15:01 localhost /USR/SBIN/CRON[11524]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Oct 25 08:16:21 localhost crontab[11351]: (myid) END EDIT (myid)
Oct 25 08:17:01 localhost /USR/SBIN/CRON[12193]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 25 08:19:17 localhost init: Id "1" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
Oct 25 08:20:01 localhost /USR/SBIN/CRON[13206]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Oct 25 08:20:02 localhost sm-msp-queue[13222]: My unqualified host name (localhost) unknown; sleeping for retry
Oct 25 08:21:02 localhost sm-msp-queue[13222]: unable to qualify my own domain name (localhost) -- using short name
```

$ service cron status

```
[ ok ] cron is running.
```

Specifying the SHELL variable at the beginning of crontab wasn't a solution as well..

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * /usr/bin/env > /home/myid/env
* * * * * /bin/echo 'hi' > /home/myid/HI
```

I really don't have any idea why it is not working. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Setting all times in the crontab to `*` does not make sense, but this may account only for the _respawning too fast_ error. Still, i would first fix this one.

Comment: Consider bumping up the log level to 15. Also, check for cron.allow, and cron.deny in /etc

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for the suggestion. I tried with `*/5 * * * *` but still I couldn't get `/home/myid/env` and `/home/myid/HI`. The error message `respawning too fast` is not fixed yet.

Comment: @dash-o Thanks for the comment. I do not have cron.allow and cron.deny in /etc/ (I guess this means all users can use cron). I haven't heard about the log level. Could you please tell me how to bump up the log level?

Comment: @Kwonil from man 'cron',: cron -L15. Also, consider 'strace -f cron -f' as root, may give yu some hints about the 'respawn too fast'

Comment: @dash-o 
Here is what I have: https://pastebin.com/GhPiLHK5

Comment: @Kwonil : What is the `/` character supposed to do in your crontab entry? My manpage for crontab doesn't list this as valid syntax.